# Speed up web-application with cookies for example

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, caching, cookies

Right now i use this code to get a random text in my web-application.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
         $("#content").load("load.php")
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })
```

Load.php is loading a random text from the database. Is their anything i can do to speedup this session. It would be great if someone also have and idea how the webbapplication could be used without 3G and WiFi.

Comment: You want to low request response time or cache results of random text on client's side? Choose what you want.

Comment: I think that caching would be best for the users. @DenisErmolin

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your php code a cache function.

When you load the random text, write it into `/cache/mytext.cache` and write an unix timestamp into `/cache/mytext.info`

Now, on top of your php script, read `/cache/mytext.info` and check if it's too old, if so, generate a new text and update the timestamp of mytext.info, else, load as text the content of /cache/mytext.cache

```
// Fetch the timestamp saved in /cache/mytext.info
$cachedate = file_get_contents('./cache/mytext.info', true);

// If timestamp + _× seconds_ is < of current time  
if(($cachedate + 3600) < time()) {

    // Fetch your new random text and store into $mytext
    // for example: $mytext = getrandomtext();

    // Write into /cache/mytext.cache your new random text
    $fp = fopen('./cache/mytext.cache', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $mytext);
    fclose($fp);

    // Update timestamp written into /cache/mytext.info
    $fp = fopen('./cache/mytext.info', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, time());
    fclose($fp);

}

// Your random text is into $mytext
$mytext = file_get_contents('./cache/mytext.cache', true);

// Print it with echo
echo $mytext;
```

Comment: How do i print the text then? I'm new in this case, sorry! @fez-vrasta

Answer (score 0):

Cache a single request in the browser and use jQuery's really useful, and much underused, Deferreds http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/, of which an ajax call is an instance, to make sure it only gets loaded once the content has arrived

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nextContent = $.get('/load.php');//preload the result of the first random text request
  var clicked = false;

  $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
     if (!clicked) { // prevent sending loads of requests if user reclicks impatiently
        clicked = true;

        nextContent.done(function (response) { 
          console.log('yay')
          $("#content").html(response); // print the text
          clicked = false;
          nextContent = $.get('/load.php'); //preload the next request
        })
     }
     evt.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

Comment: Should i replace this with my old code? It dosen't work right now when i replace that.

Comment: I've edited the code sample to hopefully fix any bug - here is a working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/XBcw6/1/, where the response times are virtually instantaneous